# Capture value from each selected row of component in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView in my application, It has four components that look like this

```
Hour string | Hour title string | minutes string |  Minutes title string
```

in the hour string I have an array of strings

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Hour title string = Hrs

Minutes string is an array of strings

> 0,15,30,45

and Minutes title string = Mins

I would like to know how to capture the component 0 and 3 values at the same time.

This is what I'm doing with my didselectrow method.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Handle the selection
    NSString *hours;
    NSString *minutes;

    hours = [hoursArrayPicker objectAtIndex:0];
    minutes = [minutesArrayPicker objectAtIndex:1];

    hoursCellString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ hrs and %@ min",hours, minutes];
    [sheetsTableView reloadData];
}
```

But I'm not capturing the right information.

Comment: Have you set the delegate method `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`?

Comment: @the_UB yes I have set that to 4, It displays everything correctly, however I just not sure what code to use to retrive the values  from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Handle the selection
    NSString *hours;
    NSString *minutes;


    hours = [hoursArrayPicker objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    minutes = [minutesArrayPicker objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];


    hoursCellString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ hrs and %@ min",hours, minutes];
    [sheetsTableView reloadData];
}
```